# Is it possible to determine where a range starts and ends in a different worksheet by using a standard Excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook with 2 worksheets.

Worksheet #1 contains a range of values that I need to use for calculations in worksheet #2.

The range runs from A1:A10.

Is it possible to use a formula that can identify these start and end values without me having to explicitly hard-code them? Additionally, I'd like Excel to name the range once it locates it, so that I can use the name as an input parameter for a subsequent SUMPRODUCT() function.

I'm trying to avoid using VBA, but not sure if what I am trying to do is possible with off-the-shelf formulas.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic range with a known starting point is easy enough by creating a named range and using the formula:

```
=$A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))
```

However if A1 is going to change it becomes:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Sheet1!$A:$A<>0),0),0)),Sheet1!$A:$A,FALSE)&":A"& COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)+MATCH(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Sheet1!$A:$A<>0),0),0)),Sheet1!$A:$A,FALSE)-1)
```

again as a named range.

Note that this will only work if there is not other data in the A column other than that of interest.